# Find integral $\int_0^1 x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to find the integral
$$\int_0^1 x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx$$

I tried by substituting $x=\cos a$. But it's leading to a form $\sin2a\cdot\tan a/2$ which I can't integrate further.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try to multiply by
$$\frac{\sqrt{1 + x}}{\sqrt{1 + x}}$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that $u = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ works.

Comment: Put $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=u^2$

Comment: @ArghyadipPal Welcome to Math SE. FYI, an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Csqrt%7B1-x%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1) includes the AoPS thread [Integral](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2034021p14352675) where its (b) part is quite similar to what you're asking about.

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} x \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx$$
Let $x=\cos 2t$, then
$$I=-2\int_{\pi/4}^{0} \cos 2t \sin 2t \tan t dt=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \left[ \cos 2t-\cos^2 2t\right] dt$$ $$=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \cos 2t dt -\int_{0}^{\pi/4} (1+\cos 4t)~ dt$$
$$\implies I=2\frac{\sin 2t}{2}\bigg|_{0}^{\pi/4} - \frac{\pi} {4}-\frac{\sin 4t}{4}\bigg|_{0}^{\pi/4}=1-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well I tried this problem yesterday so here is my solution .

Let $x= \cos (2a)$; hence ,$\mathrm dx=2\sin(2a) \mathrm da$
putting this value you will get
$x\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\\=\cos (2a)\cdot \tan a\cdot 2\sin (2a)\\
=\cos (2a)\cdot \tan a\cdot 4\sin a \cdot \cos a
\\=\cos (2a)\cdot 4(\sin a)^2 \\=2\cos (2a)\cdot (1-\cos (2a))
\\=2\cos (2a) -2(\cos 2a)^2 \\=2\cos 2a -(1+\cos (4a))$

I think you can do the rest.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the given integral is an integral over $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ times a rational function of $x$, so any of the three [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)
leads to an integral of a rational function, which can be further done by partial fraction decomposition. In fact, the third substitution is (up to sign)
$$
t = \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\ ,
$$
which is already a piece of the puzzle, so we try it first.
Then *formally*
$\displaystyle
t^2 =\frac{1-x}{1+x}
=\frac2{1+x} -1
$, so
$\displaystyle
1+t^2 =\frac{1-x}{1+x}
=\frac2{1+x} 
$, so
$\displaystyle
1+x =\frac{1-x}{1+x}
=\frac2{1+t^2} 
$, so we have $x$ and $dx$ in terms of $t$,

$\displaystyle
x =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} 
$, and
$\displaystyle
dx = d(1+x)=d\left(\frac2{1+t^2}\right)
=-\frac2{(1+t^2)^2}\cdot 2t\; dt
$.
This reduces the given integral to a rational one, *formally*:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1x\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\; dx
&=
\int_1^0 \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \cdot t\cdot \frac{-2}{(1+t^2)^2}\cdot 2t\; dt
=
\int_0^1 \frac{4t^2(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\left[
\frac{3t^3 + t}{(1+t^2)^2} - \arctan t
\right]_0^1
=1-\frac \pi4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

Similarly, we can try for an alternative proof an other Euler substitution,
we use $t$ such that
$$
\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1-tx\ .
$$
After squaring, cancelling the one, simplifying by $x$, isolating $x$ on one side, we get $x$ as an explicit function of $t$,
$\displaystyle x=\frac {2t}{1+t^2}$.

The formal derivation gives
$\displaystyle dx=d\left(\frac {2t}{1+t^2}\right)=\frac{2(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}\; dt$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1x\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\; dx
&=
\int_0^1x\cdot\frac 1{1+x}\sqrt{1-x^2}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^1\frac {2t}{1+t^2}\cdot\frac 1{\frac {(1+t)^2}{1+t^2}}\cdot
\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\; \frac{2(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}\; dt
\\
&= \int_0^1\frac {4t(1-t)^2}{(1+t^2)^3}\; dt
\\
&=
\left[
\frac{t-t^3}{(1+t^2)^2}
- \frac 2{1+t^2}
- \arctan t
\right]_0^1
=1-\frac \pi4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

Answer (score 0):

Hint..substitute $x=\cos2\theta$ and you get a simple trig integral…

Comment: Objection: hint is not an answer. This should be comment.

Comment: @algevristis there are plenty of accepted answers on this site which are just hints and not full solutions.